# JPA: Is it possible for the target of a relationship to be a non entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

The following code is in Kotlin.

I've a `TestExecutionSummary` entity

```
@Entity
class TestExecutionSummary : Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    lateinit var id: TestExecutionId
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], mappedBy = "testExecutionSummary")
    var failures: List<TestFailure> = mutableListOf()     
}
@Embeddable
data class TestExecutionId(
        var stepExecutionId: Long,
        var jobExecutionId: Long
) : Serializable
```

and a `TestFailure` entity

```
@Entity
class TestFailure : Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null
    @Column(length = 999)
    lateinit var testId: String
    @JoinColumns(
            JoinColumn(name = "stepExecutionId", referencedColumnName = "stepExecutionId"),
            JoinColumn(name = "jobExecutionId", referencedColumnName = "jobExecutionId")
    )
    @ManyToOne
    lateinit var testExecutionSummary: TestExecutionSummary
    @Column(length = 999)
    var message: String? = null
}
```

This works fine, but what's bugging me is that `TestFailure` has no independent existence, and doesn't really qualify as an entity IMO. Is it possible to maintain the shown relationship without making `TestFailure` an entity?

Comment: IMO the relation should be denormalized. But why you need a list ? could a flag (+columns if needed)  to tell that the test is faild be sufficient ?

Comment: @MontassarElBéhi I don't follow. If one test execution results in multiple failures. how would you persist that with "a flag (+columns if needed)"?

Comment: Personally, I find that considering a relationship to be an entity can often be quite useful. It also often happens that you later find additional properties that you want to add to this relationship/entity. I say just embrace the idea...

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar sorry but when I see an entity whithout a chronological state (generally a date) I prefer to keep the last state on the main entity: failed[1/0].  So maybe this is meanful and the question is to forget about the summary as an entity (integrate the Id colums but not as Id in failure entity). Summary can be a simple pojo later. what do you think ?

Comment: @MontassarElBéhi I still don't understand what you're saying. Feel free to provide a gist with actual code. Meanwhile, I found a solution that I'm happy with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2.0 has [ElementCollection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) which is exactly what I'm looking for.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(
        name = "TEST_FAILURE",
        joinColumns = [
            JoinColumn(name = "stepExecutionId", referencedColumnName = "stepExecutionId"),
            JoinColumn(name = "jobExecutionId", referencedColumnName = "jobExecutionId")
        ]
)
var failures: List<TestFailure> = mutableListOf()

@Embeddable
class TestFailure : Serializable {
    @Column(length = 999)
    lateinit var testId: String
    @Column(length = 999)
    var message: String? = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for @Embeddable but it is not available for @OneToMany.
See [Mapping Single Table to Embeddable Collection in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318387/mapping-single-table-to-embeddable-collection-in-jpa) for workaround

Comment: I'm not asking for `Embeddable`. I'm saying that the `id` in the `TestFailure` table only exists because it's an `Entity`; no one uses the `id` for anything. It'd make lot more sense to be able to remove the `id` while keeping the rest.